# Is it safe to secure a racy variable with another racy variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, x86, volatile

```
void foo(volatile int& a, volatile int& b, bool threadOne) {
    if (threadOne) {
        //EDIT: switched the following two lines
        b = 10;
        a = 5;
    } else {
        while(a == 0);
        cout << a << b;
    }
}

//somewhere else
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
std::thread th1(foo, a, b, true);
std::thread th2(foo, a, b, false);
```

Is this safe on x86 i.e. every legal interleaving of instructions according to the c++ standard and the x86 reference will print "510"? My hypothesis is that it actually is safe.

Comment: I don't think the word "safe" actually means anything, and you sure did't bother defining it, so -1 for that. Your code has undefined behaviour as far as C++ is concerned.

Comment: "Is this safe on x86 i.e. every legal interleaving of instructions according to the c++ standard and the x86 reference will print "510"? " Isn't that a definition?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Safe definitely [does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) mean something in a multi-threaded context, which is why the question is tagged with `multithreading`.

Comment: There are things you can get away with on a single core that will bite you on a multi-core architecture. I don't think what you have there would be safe on a multicore.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. This is UB.

Comment: @ben: Not really. C++ doesn't normatively contain "instructions" or "interleaving", nor does it define a mapping to x86 instructions.

Answer (score 5):

§1.10 [intro.multithread] (quoting N4140):

> 6 Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a
>   memory location (1.7) and the other one accesses or modifies the same
>   memory location.
>
> 23 Two actions are *potentially concurrent* if
>
> - they are performed by different threads, or
> - they are unsequenced, and at least one is performed by a signal handler.
>
> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two
>   potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is
>   not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the
>   special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race
>   results in undefined behavior.

One of your threads reads from `a`, another writes to `a`, neither is atomic, and neither of these two potentially concurrent conflicting actions happens before the other. Hence, you have a data race and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** No, no, no, a thousand times no.

As far as the C++11 standard is concerned, the program has undefined behavior because it has a data race (`a` is read and written by concurrent executions without synchronization). So no, it won't always print 510. `volatile` has no effect at all on that, it doesn't mean what `volatile` in C# and Java means.

I also suspect (but can't assert with full confidence) that, independently, the x86 chip can also break this program, though perhaps not due to *interleaving*. However,

1. The new value of `a` may come into effect before the new value of `b` becomes visible (since no memory fence prevents the chip from reordering the writes).
2. The new value of either variable may never become visible to the second thread. Check out cache coherence protocols.

You're playing with fire. For no good reason to boot, condition variables are cheap. If the expected delay is small enough for a condition variable to *not* be cheap, then a spinlock (with proper synchronization, i.e. atomics) will be cheap instead.

Comment: Your suspicion regarding a never becoming visible is wrong IMHO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol

Comment: @ben: Actually, he's entirely correct. The compiler could choose to store `a` in a register, in which case cache coherence protocols don't apply.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The `volatile` qualifier may prevent that (with the caveat that the standard does not know or care about registers, so this effect would be implementation specific).

Comment: @delnan: It might, sort of, but I'm not convinced that `volatile` is defined well enough to say that with any certainty.

Comment: "In computer programming, particularly in the C, C++, C#, and Java programming languages, the volatile keyword indicates that a value may change between different accesses, even if it does not appear to be modified." (wikipedia) If the compiler puts (in the example above) a in a register it simply does not fulfill this definition.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm pretty certain that in any reasonably popular compiler, there will be a memory write. It may use a register along the way (if only because memory-memory `mov` isn't a thing on x86) but the write should be guaranteed by `volatile` (the implementation's take on it, not the standard's).

Comment: @delnan According to my class it holds for x86: "Writes are not reordered with other writes." so your 1. point is not true I think.

Comment: @ben: That's not what `volatile` really means in C or C++. The real definition is: "Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to rules of the abstract machine." This code doesn't have any volatile objects, only volatile references to non-volatile objects, so a global optimizer can ignore the `volatile` completely in this case. The least you need to do to get some real meaning is to change the definitions of `a` and `b` to be `volatile`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I forgot about inter procedural optimizations, good point.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That was a super helpful hint. I thought the volatile on the references would refer to the objects i.e. the integers in this case.

Comment: @ben: It sort of does, but only sort of. Which is to say, if you're going to refer to a volatile object, you need a reference to volatile to do so. Absent global optimization, references via that reference will probably have to follow the rules for `volatile` (so reads and writes have to refer to memory). But a global optimizer can prove that there are no actual volatile objects here, which (probably) allows it to ignore the `volatile` qualifier on the reference.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think I see what you mean. But I don't think the compiler would optimize like that. After all it could be that I compile the above and want to link the file somewhere and pass a real volatile object into the function. If it would have removed volatile then this would break modularity right?

Comment: @ben It's free to inline the function and remove `volatile` of the inlined copy while leaving it in the copy called by other modules. Also there are link-time optimizations. You're only trying to understand, not trying to find an excuse to stick with the broken code, right?

Comment: @delnan I don't care about that the code is broken. Maybe it does appear as if I'm trying to "defend" my code. But that's the way I'm obtaining knowledge. I stated that I assume my code works out. Now if somebody tells me that it does not I want to know why to increase my knowledge and find out what caused my wrong hypothesis. In that sense I'm "defending" my code until somebody comes up with an undeniable fact that proofs that my code is wrong. As for this question I feel like it comes down to "the standard says it's not working". But the why remains somewhat hidden.

Comment: @ben: Global optimization is (mostly) done at link time, which lets it know about what's happening globally, not just within a given translation unit. An `int volatile &` basically means "this *could* refer to a `volatile` object." At the global level, it can see when it actually *does* refer to a volatile object (and when it doesn't) and generate code accordingly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you for the hint. The semantics that I thought of in the code I posted were really to have `a` and `b` declared as volatile in that case.

Comment: @ben: I kind of figured that. Still doesn't fix the code though. Although volatile (at least sort of) guarantees that writes to volatile objects will happen in order, it does nothing to guarantee that reads of those objects in another thread will *see* them as happening in order. That will happen with cache coherent architectures like x86, but there are also machines with various looser levels of cache coherence for which it won't work.

Comment: @JerryCoffin As stated in my question I actually care only about x86. Now it would still not work right? (Because the c++ standard says so) Actually I ran code like this today and it worked out fine. Differently put: Is it that the c++ standard does not define behavior because there could be different cache coherence protocols being used? But on x86 it's actually safe?

Comment: @ben: On x86 *with the right compiler* it's almost certainly safe (e.g., MS gives `volatile` some extra meaning that's not in the standard that will guarantee what you want). Otherwise, all bets are off (and a new version of the compiler might change the behavior too).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Okay, thank you for all the explanations.